# Need help to understand a react-native code that uses reduce() on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

This code is from a simple React Native Contacts app, it's supposed to use `reduce` method to:

for each contact in the array `contacts`, extract and uppercase the first letter, then `return` an object that maintains all the previous keys of object and appends this current contact to the key which matches it's first letter.

//contacts is an array of objects {key, name, phone}

```
  const contactsByLetter = props.contacts.reduce((obj, contact) => {
    const firstLetter = contact.name[0].toUpperCase()
    return {
      ...obj,
      [firstLetter]: [...(obj[firstLetter] || []), contact],
    }
  }, {})
```

reduce syntax is `arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])`
First, I don't see where the `obj` argument is in the syntax. Second, I understand how spread notation work but I don't get the whole return part specially `[...(obj[firstLetter]`

The code is in this file [SectionListContacts file](https://github.com/EimanKDS/EimanKDS/blob/master/SectionListContacts.js), the entire code [here](https://github.com/EimanKDS/EimanKDS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appends this current contact to the key which matches it's first letter:

```js
  [firstLetter]: [...(obj[firstLetter] || []), contact],
```

For example,

```js
{a: ['user a1', 'user a2'] }
```

so,

```
[a]: [...(['user a1', 'user a2'] || []), 'user a3']
```

then,

```
[a]: ['user a1', 'user a2', 'user a3']
```

[**EDITED**]

`obj` is the previous value. The first value of it is the initial value set like

```js
const initialValue = 10;
[1,2,3].reduce((prev, current) => prev + current, initialValue)
// 10 + (1+2+3) = 16
```

In your case, `obj` initial value is `{}`.

Comment: thank you very much I understand this part now, but do you know the answer for my first question, how come we can pass `obj` in `reduce` when the syntax for `reduce`  is only passing the `currentValue` argument and no `obj` ?